# product attribute front end html not rendering properly

Tags: product-attribute, magento2, frontend-model

I created front end model for custom product attribute.but

in the front end output coming like this   `<b>pencilval</b>` instead of **pencilval**

```
namespace Some\Pencil\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend;

    class Pencil extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend
    {
        /**
         * Retrieve attribute value
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getValue(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)
        {
            $data = '';
            $value = parent::getValue($object);
            if ($value) {
                $data = '<b>' . $value . '</b>';
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on showing your new attribute in the "Additional Data" section of the product detail page, what you are trying will not be possible.  Here is why:

The value that is returned from getValue() will always be escaped.  There is also no way to change the styling of the  for a single attribute without changing the attributes.phtml itself:

```
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
    <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?php echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set up `is_html_allowed_on_front` flag in installer script for your custom attribute or add this at the beginning of your `getValue` method

```
$this->getAttribute()->setData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::IS_HTML_ALLOWED_ON_FRONT, 1);
```